# Find the orbits of the system: $\dot{x} = y +x^2y$, $\dot{y} = 3x + xy^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

[This is my answer. So the orbits is $y = \sqrt{c(1 + x^2) - 3}$?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPpXT.jpg)

Comment: If $u:=\frac{x}{y}$, then we have $\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}t}=1-3u^2$.  Then, you can solve for $u$, but not sure how much this helps.

Comment: I think it should be $C_1x^2+C_2$. Solving the differential equation we get $ \ln (y^2+3) = \ln (x^2+1) + c$. Since $\ln (a) + \ln (b) = \ln(ab)$ we get $ \ln ( y^2 + 3) = \ln (cx^2+c)$. Then you can remove the logarithm and you should be done. Note that the constant $c$ is not actually the exact same one used each time, but it's an arbitrary constant so we can just keep renaming it.

Comment: My solution is $y = \sqrt{c(1 + x^2) - 3}$. I just attached it in the question. Could you help to take a look?

Comment: Note that $$\frac{2y\dot y}{3+y^2}=xy=\frac{2x\dot x}{1+x^2}$$ hence $$\log(3+y^2)=\log(1+x^2)+C$$ that is, $$3+y^2=c\cdot(1+x^2)$$

Comment: @Cataline "I think it should be C1x2+C2" No, $c\cdot(1+x^2)$ is correct.

Answer (score 0):

A method more or less equivalent to yours, but motivated by groups $(1+x^2)$ and $(3+y^2)$.

$\begin{cases} x = \sinh(u)\\ y = \sqrt{3}\sinh(v)\end{cases}\iff
\begin{cases} 1+x^2=\cosh(u)^2\\ 3+y^2=3\cosh(v)^2 \end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}\dot x=\cosh(u)\dot u=y\cosh(u)^2\\
\dot y=\sqrt{3}\cosh(v)\dot v=3x\cosh(v)^2
\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases}\dot u = \sqrt{3}\sinh(v)\cosh(u)\\\dot v = \sqrt{3}\sinh(u)\cosh(v)\end{cases}$

$\implies\tanh(v)\dot v=\tanh(u)\dot u$

$\implies \ln(\cosh(v))=\ln(\cosh(u))+cst$

$\implies\cosh(v)=A\cosh(u)$ with $A>0$

So with $c=3A^2$ we get $3+y^2=c(1+x^2)$ too.